# The formal language of grammar

Tags: automation, grammar, formal-languages

I'v tried to deduce from these grammars their language:

For the first one, i think (but not quiet sure) the language is: 
{a^(i)b^(j) | i mod 2 = 0 and j > 0}

and for the second one, i don't have a single clue.

```
1.
    G = ({S,A,B},{a,b},S,P) 
    P:
    S -> AAB
    A -> aaA | aa
    B -> bB | b

2.
    G = ({S,A,B},{a,b},S,P)
    P:
    S -> AB
    A -> aAb | epsilon
    B -> bBa | epsilon
```

To reach the formal language of the first grammar, I tried to cut it several times in different forms and saw that 'a' necessarily repeated an even number of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the first one, i think (but not quiet sure) the language is: {a^(i)b^(j) | i mod 2 = 0 and j > 0}

Counterexample: `aab` is in that language, but not in the language of the grammar.

Aside: rather than

```
{a^(i) ... | i mod 2 = 0 ...}`
```

I think it's more common to say

```
{a^(2i) ... | ...}
```

> for the second one, i don't have a single clue.

The language derived from `S` is just the concatenation of the languages derived from `A` and `B`.

`A` has 2 alternatives, one recursive and one not, so any sentence derived from `A` results from k>=0 applications of the recursive production, followed by a single application of the non-recursive production. From that, you should be able to get the language derived from `A`.

Similarly for `B`, then concatenate them.

Comment: Thank you! it was really helpful :)